# what is Sherman-Morrison formula

Tags: matrix, preconditioning, matrix-factorization

Can someone please explain what is the Sherman-Morrison formula and it's specialities when it comes to matrix calculations? I'm a little bit confused on understanding how the preconditioning works with Sherman-Morrison formula.

Comment: What do you expect that you cannot trivially find by searching the web?

Comment: Please edit the post with: what do you do not understand? So people may be can help you

Comment: This question is more suited to math.stackexchange, there in the linear-algebra and numerical mathematics section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sherman-Morrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula) formula helps to find the inverse of the matrix cheap after a rank-1 update. [Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) does it for a low-rank update (not necessarily rank-1).

In short,

1. You have a matrix $A$ and **you already have a computed** $A^{-1}$.
2. For some reason, you need to do a rank-1 update to $A$. This rank-1 update can be described as an [outer-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) of two vectors $u$ and $v$.
3. So, you want an inverse of $(A+uv^T)$, but you don't want to redo all the calculations. Can you reuse your knowledge of $A^{-1}$? Yes.
4. Sherman-Morrison tells you that 
   $$
   (A+uv^T)^{-1} = A^{-1}-\frac{A^{-1}uv^TA^{-1}}{1+v^tA^{-1}u}
   $$
   which allows [huge savings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula#Application) since you are just performing relatively cheap manipulations with an already obtained $A^{-1}$.

I strongly encourage you to read at least the Wikipedia articles regarding this topic in order to get an understanding about

- numerical stability
- requirements for the formula to be applicable

Important notes:

- calculations of the inverse should be avoided at all costs
- same ideas (SM, SMW) usually can be applied to factorizations, where they are extremely useful